# How to get the crash log for Receiver apps that are crashed on the chromecast device?

Tags: google-cast

I am looking as how to get the crash log for my receiver app which is on chromecast device.

I have a custom sender app and a receiver app. I am using player to fetch the content URL from sender app and playback the content in receiver app. After some time of playback or data streaming between sender and receiver app, suddenly I observe that Receiver app crashes and sends TCP packet with RST flag enabled(which means receiver app is closed the connection). I tried to check the debug logging in debugger tool, but as the Receiver app is terminated due to crash, the debugger tool is disconnected.

I want to know how to get the crash log and the error log of our receiver app running on chromecast device in this scenario?

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try debugging for a Chromecast device, where you navigate to your receiver's IP address on port 9222.

http://:9222

The logs will still be available in 9222 and you can see them.

Comment: Thanks for this information. This is similar to what we can get from the debugger tool details provided in the cast documentation (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging). Both method that you mentioned and what is mentioned in documentation are same. In both cases when Receiver app crashes, there is no connection to the device and we can't get logs. I am looking for backtrace information or crash dump log, any idea how can I get that?.